Why is the Pythagorean theorem necessary for surface area of revolutions instead of simply approximating with $\mathrm{d}x$?
Why isn't it sufficient to just integrate over $\mathrm{d}x$, and how does the Pythagorean theorem come into play when finding the surface area? What are we missing when we only consider $\mathrm{d}x$, and how does the formula
$$
\sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \ ?
$$
I get that using the Pythagorean theorem version, which gives the "correct" answer for stuff like circles and only using $\mathrm{d}x$ wouldn't, so it's correct, I just don't get why can't we just say this inf. piece of the curve is approximately $\mathrm{d}x$ when you zoom like we could for the volume of revolution. What if we did take into account the Pythagorean version for the volume, should the answer not change because it's more accurate?

Consider a line of nonzero slope.  We can easily determine the length of the line.  We approximate this line only considering $\mathrm{d}x$.
One property of Calculus approximations that work is that as you cut objects up into finer and finer partitions, the difference between your approximation and the true value decreases.
For our line of nonzero slope, let's see what happens on the interval $[0,1]$.  We partition with boundaries
$$  0 = x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n = 1  \text{.}  $$
Since we only want to use the $\mathrm{d}x$s, we only account for the $\Delta x$s in the finite sum.  The contributions from each interval in the partition are, respectively, $x_1 - x_0$, $x_2 - x_1$, ... , and $x_n - x_{n-1}$.  If we add these up, the $x_1$s cancel, the $x_2$s cancel, ..., and the $x_{n-1}$s cancel, leaving $x_n - x_0 = 1$.
Notice that we didn't say how big $n$ is.  It doesn't matter.  Each choice of $n$ gives the approximate length $1$.  Slicing finer and finer, we only get the length $1$.  But on the interval $[0,1]$, only the line of zero slope has length $1$ -- every other line is longer.
If we only account for the $\mathrm{d}x$, we replace the
$$  \sqrt{ (\Delta x_i)^2 + (\Delta y_i)^2 }
    = |\Delta x_i| \sqrt{ 1 + (\Delta y_i)^2/(\Delta x_i)^2 }  $$
correct length of the piece of line in the $i^{\text{th}}$ interval with the width of the interval.  Adding up just the widths always gives $1$ and adding up all the length formula (pythagorean hypotenuses) gives the correct length (exactly, for any partition, because lines are very, very easy to approximate).
We don't want to wrongly compute that the length of a curve is just the width of its graph, so we pick points along its length, use the distance formula to find the distance between successive points (so using the Pythagorean formula), and add those up to approximate the length of the curve.  If we partition more finely, the chain of line segments that we approximate the curve by actually does more closely approximate the length of the curve.  If we only account for the $x$-components or the $y$-components, we find out more about the width of the graph of the curve or the height of the graph of the curve (increased in potentially complicated ways by curves that wave back and forth instead of just crossing their width or height).

Start with a cone. $L$ is slant generator length.Pythagoras theorem used at first to find differential slant length of a cone
$$
dL=\sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \ 
$$
The theorem served its purpose.. to find generator length and is not any more required.
$$
L=\int\sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \ 
$$
$$ \text{Cone curved area of revolution}=\pi y_{max} L $$
$$
\text{ Any curve, swept curved area of revolution}=\int (2 \pi y)\sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \right)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x . 
$$

The leap im missing in understanding this reasoning is couldn't i make the same argument for volume of a surface of revolution, but we don't. Instead of calcualting the partial volumn using the volume of the frustum of the cone (like we calculate the surface area of the frustum of a cone in your example) we just use dx
